# CKEditor custom combobox plugin width

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, ckeditor

I have implemented a custom combobox plugin for CKEditor that I have called "tokens", which allows for the insertion of custom tags into the editor. The plugin is working as expected; I used the code in my custom plugin.js:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('tokens', { init: function (editor) { ...
```

My problem is that I must give a custom width to this combobox, by modifying the style for the default kama skin in skins/kama/editor.css. I tried the following and it didn't work:

```
.cke_skin_kama .cke_tokens .cke_text {width:100px !important;}
```

This works for the built-in comboboxes, i.e. "font":

```
.cke_skin_kama .cke_font .cke_text {width:60px !important;}
```

In my online search, I found only instances of how to tweak the width of built-in combobox plugins, i.e. "font" and "format". I need to know how to do this for a custom one.